# Dart Animate issue

Tags: multithreading, events, onclick, jquery-animate, dart

I am using dart animate package. Basically I want to slide a button to left

```
// Register to handle 'onClick'
buttonElemet.onClick.listen(onClick);

void onClick(Event e) {        
    ButtonElement button = // get the button that you want to animate
    int left = // get the left of the button from style

    animate(button, properties: {'left':left + 100}, duration: 0);
}
```

This works as expected when the button is clicked manually. But I need to simulate series of button clicks (basically to shuffle the puzzle board).

So I invoke the click event(s) programatically using:

```
for (...) {
    int numberToSlide = // select a random number to slide

    ButtonElement button = querySelector('#btn' + numberToSlide.toString());
    button.click();
}
```

When this happens, the 'left' in onClick event is not coming as predicted. After a quite a debugging I suspect the animate happens in a thread and while the button is getting animated the next event gets into 'onClick'.

Any idea or thoughts around this problem? Thanks.

Note: I have a similar code but using jQuery animate. I've no issues with jquery animate though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a second method

```
void shuffle(int left) { ... }
```

Call this in onClick and in your simulate method.

A good pattern: if you have code that needs to be run via two code paths (some UI, some not UI) factor out the UI-independent code.

Comment: kevmo, it is not about the code arrangement.. the issue is due to some run time behavior. basically I am using button.style.left to retrieve the left value. But I observe is this value is coming inconsistently. What I observed is while animate is still changing this value, the next iteration is fetching a (wrong) value. I am looking for a solution to fix such issue in dart.

Comment: Madhan: I'm guessing this is not a Dart issue, but due to behavior in how animated CSS properties report their values.